# jQuery slide the whole page

Tags: jquery, button, slide

I have seen this site on the internet: http://etinspires.com/ on the right side there is a "+" button ... when i click the button the whole side slides from right to left ... can somebody tell me how it works? I have googled but there is no code snippets that can explain me how it works ... in the source code of the site I didn't find the exact source code that I can learn how it works.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 1):

The Basic's

```
$('#YourButton').click(function(e) {
      $('#foo').animate({
          'left' : '30px'
      });                 
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eyMfY/)**

Comment: thx mohammend! and the html markup? ... is it lik <div id="container"> <div id="container-main">test</div> <div id="container-slide">here the slide text</div></div> ?

Comment: see fiddle.. you will get the idea.